# Are we able to search for and highlight a card in react-trello?

Tags: reactjs, trello

I have about 100 cards on a trello board in 9 lanes. There is vertical scrolling and horizontal scrolling. Is it possible to have a search box above the board or within a lane to allow for searching a card based on the text inside of it to allow for easier drag-drop between lanes? Perhaps highlight all cards that contain the user-entered search keywords? If yes, can you please guide me on how to accomplish?